# PhoneGap application requires native iOS code for background service?

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have a PhoneGap app and it checks your location every 5 minutes and reports it back etc.. to do this When the app needs to run in put at the background .

For Android I have written native code but for iOS will this work?

I'm not even sure how you would implement native objective c into PhoneGap as they are very different compilers etcthe it pause.

Any advice would be appreciatedWhen it come back to front, it will resume all remaining operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write a Plugin to do this. A plugin will allow you to write Objective-C code and link it back to a JS function. Here are a few tutorials:

[From Apache](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/guide_plugin-development_ios_index.md.html#Developing%20a%20Plugin%20on%20iOS)

[From Adobe](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/extending-phonegap-with-native-plugins-for-ios.html)

[Another](http://phonegap.pbworks.com/w/page/36753496/How%20to%20Create%20a%20PhoneGap%20Plugin%20for%20iOS)

Here is also a big list of Plugins people have already created: [iOS Plugins](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS)

Comment: Thanks. I got a reply from a PhoneGap rep and he said; Can PhoneGap run in background and update GeoLocation? 
Short answer, No. When the app put at the background the it pause. When it come back to front, it will resume all remaining operation.